# bootstrap 4 mobile navigation menu will not stay open on home page only

Tags: javascript, mobile, menu, navigation, bootstrap-4

http://jkdev.xyz/ohwala/index.html

I'm working on my first site using Bootstrap 4 beta.  I realized the mobile navigation menu doesn't want to stay open on the HOME PAGE ONLY. When the hamburger icon is clicked the nav menu opens and then closes immediately. The menu page everything works fine.  I've been googling to no avail.
Thank you in advance for your time!  (FYI the site is not complete in case you come across other links, etc not working. My main issue currently is only the mobile navigation function)

Comment: do you have all the libraries installed like popperjs ?

Comment: You are using older syntax ,use syntax for bootstrap 4 beta which you can find on https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: Put the relevant code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had assumed they would update the code inside the js files used in alpha.  came to realize there were newer version of the libraries and popper.js to be added as well.  rookie mistake huh!